# Where is the pet store?

Tags: the-sims-freeplay

I was playing sims freeplay on my iPod yesterday but could not find the pet store. Where is the pet store in the preteens are here update?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the town map and click on the Pet Store, it is a pink circle with a dog in it.

You may have to build it first though if you haven't already. It is next to the park & the hobby shop

Answer (score 1):

The pet shop is located on the town map between the salon and the hobby store. It is indicated by a pink and yellow icon with the silhouettes of a dog and two cats.

[image: The pet shop, highlighted in red]